# Show DevTools in tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How could I show Chrome DevTools in a tab?

I've looked through the docs and made a search on Chrome Store, but it looks like there's nothing like this. It could be that DevTools are shown in their own window to counter some security issues, of which I'm not aware yet.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. The only options are:

1. Dock them horizontally below
2. Dock them vertically on the right
3. Dock them in a separate window.

More information can be found on their documentation at https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#dock-to-right

Comment: This is possible anyway (as we're talking about Turing-complete platform), the question is how. I managed to run DevTools in a tab with `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools.html?dockSide=bottom&toolbarColor=rgba(242,241,240,1)` URL. Though, it's not functional, as we need to somehow set a target.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl + Shift + C , then click on the small icon on bottom left of devTool which is used them to dock dev tool to a separate tab.

Comment: That's a separate window, and I know about that button. The problem is that I don't like an idea of one more window on screen.